# RDLC Report With Empty DataSet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm currently trying to get an rdlc report to work, and it works fine except when I pass an empty dataset to it (the dataset is determined dynamically at runtime -- ugly, but this is the code I was passed and I'm not quite experienced enough to really feel confident about wiping it and rewriting it). When I pass it an empty DataSet, it fails with an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The strange thing is, I have another report that gets passed a similar DataSet, but it doesn't fail. I'm not quite sure why one report with an empty DataSet is failing, but the other is not.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @bluefeet: You mean the XML? I can, but it's EXTREMELY lengthy. I'm talking over 1000 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. As it turns out there was a stray parameter that wasn't getting set... rebuilding the report from the ground up did the trick.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you did to fix this issue please? We're investigating something similar just now so any help would be useful!